# Caching (Ehcache) - Hibernate 2nd level cache and Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, caching, ehcache

In my web application (Spring 3.1, Hibernate 4), I am using Ehcache for Hibernate 2nd level cache and Spring @Cache. I would like to know, where to use Hibernate Cache and Spring Cache?

For Example, I have few domain classes (view in database) which I am using as lookup values on screen. I can cache them using Hibernate 2nd level cache as well as Spring @Cache.

So, in my service layer if I cache these domain objects using Spring @Cache, I would receive these objects without hitting persistence layer at all (hibernate HQL query), once cached. Is it right approach?

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your layer architecture.

Assume you have three services (or three methods within the same service) that all return a collection of `Customer` entities i.e. domain objects. If you cache at service layer there's a fair chance the same representation of a single database record will live in the cache multiple times. They are multiple objects of essentially the same information. Why? Because the results of `Service.getWhateverCustomers(String)` and `Service.getWhateverCustomers(String, Integer)` are stored under two different cache keys.

If you cache at entity level using the JPA [@Cachable](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Caching) annotation on the other hand your `Customer` entity is cached no matter from which service or service method you call the code that actually retrieves the entity. Of course the rules about when the JPA provider can/does cache an entity apply. Read up on them if you're not familiar with them.

Hope this gives you an idea which path to follow. Post follow-up comments if you have more questions and I'll edit this answer.

Comment: I agree with you on the example you gave. My case is little different. I have single method in service layer to get all lookup values. So, I have defined @cache on service layer method. (I believe, it has better performance as persistence layer is not involved at all). Some of my entities are cached using hibernate and others (like lookup values) are cached by spring. Is it right approach? or should I manage all through hibernate - neglecting little performance gain?

Comment: @Ketan, "I believe, it has better performance" - this is the wrong approach. You should **measure** not believe or guess. And as Ryan Stewart said, only ever consider caching if you have a performance issue that you cannot solve otherwise indeed. Apart from that I don't have any personal preferences. However, caching on a single layer (be it persistence or service) is of course architecturally cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The right approach is:

1. Ask yourself if you even need to mess with the complexity of caching. Is your app failing to perform up to requirements?
2. Only if the answer to the previous question is "yes", profile your app to find out where the performance problem(s) is/are.
3. Determine the appropriate way to solve a performance problem identified in step 2. It may or may not involve caching to prevent costly operations. If it does involve caching, then where to cache and which cache to use should be abundantly clear because you'll know exactly what you're trying to prevent from happening.

The moral of the story is that you don't cache because it's cool. You cache for performance. And you [only optimize code when it's proven necessary](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).